# Extracting text after "?"

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

I have a string

```
x <- "Name of the Student? Michael Sneider"
```

I want to extract "Michael Sneider" out of it.

I have used:

```
str_extract_all(x,"[a-z]+")
str_extract_all(data,"\\?[a-z]+")
```

But can't extract the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should help

```
substr(x, str_locate(x, "?")+1, nchar(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sub('.*\\?(.*)','\\1',x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- "Name of the Student? Michael Sneider"

sub(pattern = ".+?\\?" , x , replacement = '' )
```

Answer (score 2):

To take advantage of the loose wording of the question, we can go WAY overboard and use natural language processing to extract all names from the string:

```
library(openNLP)
library(NLP)
# you'll also have to install the models with the next line, if you haven't already
# install.packages('openNLPmodels.en', repos = 'http://datacube.wu.ac.at/', type = 'source')

s <- as.String(x)    # convert x to NLP package's String object

# make annotators
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
entity_annotator <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator()

# call sentence and word annotators
s_annotated <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
# call entity annotator (which defaults to "person") and subset the string
s[entity_annotator(s, s_annotated)]
## Michael Sneider
```

Overkill? Probably. But interesting, and not actually all that hard to implement, really.

Answer (score 1):

`str_match` is more helpful in this situation

```
str_match(x, ".*\\?\\s(.*)")[, 2] 
#[1] "Michael Sneider"
```